# Getting Term_id - Taxonomy Metadata plugin

Tags: terms

I've been looking everywhere but can't find any way to make this works. I am using the [Taxonomy Metadata plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-metadata/) and I am trying to display the custom metadata created. For this I use: `get_term_meta($term_id, 'my_metadata', TRUE);`. The problem is that I can't find a way to get the term_id. I am in a template page inside the loop. Here is what I have tried:

```
$term = get_term_by('name', 'name', 'custom_taxonomy');
$termid = $term->term_id;
$metadata = get_term_meta($termid, 'my_metadata', TRUE);
```

But it's not working, it just returns: `Trying to get property of non-object` for the term_id.

Could you help me please?

Thank you!

Comment: `get_term_by` isn't finding the term, either the name or the taxonomy you are passing is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I have found a way. If it can be useful for someone here is how I solved it:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'custom_taxonomy' );
if($terms) {
foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    $term_id = $term->term_id;
}
}
```

Then you can use `$term_id` in your expression.